# Binding a treeview in contextmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to bind treeview in contextmenu(using jquery).

This is my contextmenu script:

```
$(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {
                name: "Closing on Click", 
                callback: function(){ return true; }
            },
            "cut": {
                name: "Open after Click", 
                callback: function(){ return false; }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Because the treeview is a ul li oriented, how can include that in contextmenu options?

Comment: add some html of your treeview. I think that you have to change your selector

Comment: function initTrees() {
     $("#mixed").treeview({
     url: "source.php",
    });
    }
    $(document).ready( function() {
     initTrees();
     // Show menu when a list item is clicked
     $("#myList UL LI").contextMenu({
     menu: 'myMenu'
     }, function(action, el, pos) {
     });
    });
    </script>
    <div id="myList">
    <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <ul id="mixed">
    <li><span>Submenu1</span>
     <ul>
      <li><span>submenu 1.1</span>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>

Comment: while i am looking it, see you HTML you have a `ul` in `ul` `<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu"> <ul id="mixed">`. Try to correct your HTML first

Answer (score 0):

From code i guess that you use [this](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMen) plugin

so based on your html (corrected) and plugin's documentation you have

```
<div id="myMenu">
    <ul> 
        <li><span>Submenu1</span>
            <ul> 
                <li><span>submenu 1.1</span></li> 
            </ul>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

and

```
$(function() { 
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '#myMenu ul li',         
        items: {
            "edit": {
                name: "Closing on Click", 
                callback: function(){ return true; }
            },
            "cut": {
                name: "Open after Click", 
                callback: function(){ return false; }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmMMg/1/)

Comment: If I change the selector option from .context-menu-one to #myMenu ul li, my contextmenu is enabled on right click on the div. What I want to achieve is, on right click of a div, the tree should appear as my options in my context menu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106215/binding-a-treeview-in-contextmenu-revisited